# Chemfig error while trying to make a polymer

Tags: chemfig

I have the following code (which I found somewhere around this page) to make polymer figure

```
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mhchem}

 \makeatletter
  \newcommand*\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\polymer@delimleft{#1}\def\polymer@delimright{#2}}

 \newcommand*\makepolymerbraces[5]{%
 \edef\polymer@delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
 \edef\polymer@delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
 \chemmove{
\node[at=(#4),yshift=(\polymer@delimvshift)]
  {$
   \left\polymer@delimleft
     \vrule height\polymer@delimhalfdim depth\polymer@delimhalfdim width0pt
   \right.
  $};
\node[at=(#5),yshift=(\polymer@delimvshift)]
  {$
    \left.
      \vrule height\polymer@delimhalfdim depth\polymer@delimhalfdim width0pt
    \right\polymer@delimright_{\rlap{#3}}
   $};
}%
}
\makeatother
 %

 \begin{document}

  \setpolymerdelim[]

 \chemfig{-[@{b1},1.5]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]Cl)(-[6]H)-[@{b2},1.5]}
 \makepolymerbraces{40pt}{40pt}{$n$}{b1}{b2}

   \end{document}
```

No matter what I try it always gives me this error: 
!Missing $ inserted. 
!Extra }
!pacakage PFG math error: unknown function '@b1
!pacakage PFG math error: unknown function '@b2

Everything in the line where the command \chemfig{-[@{b1},1.5]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]Cl)(-[6]H)-[@{b2},1.5]}
Can anyone help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm using Texmaker and I just took any basic polymer as an example. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get no error from your code. What TeX distribution are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To compile the document (pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9)) I had to complete the preamble by `\documentclass{article}` and voilà

[image]

Invoking `mhchem` was not necessary for this.  As a side-note, in my daily use I call it by `\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}`.

Second remark: Of course you may use `chemfig`.  But if you want to depict many chemical structures, like for a report in lab classes, there are easier ways to obtain such representations.  The documentation of the `chemstyle` bundle describes some of them.  For reports, for example, or while exchanging with other colleagues (perhaps less chem-savy than you) it is more efficient and much faster to create them with a molecular editor and export them for example as *.eps / *.pdf into a designated folder within your working project.

If you work at a university, perhaps your department provides access to [Chemdraw](http://www.cambridgesoft.com/software/overview.aspx).  If your are student, [ChemDoodle](https://www.chemdoodle.com/) may be an alternative with a considerably lesser price tag (and in difference to the former, working on Win/Mac/Linux). (For a comparison of several molecular editors, consider this review [here](http://www.gunda.hu/dprogs/),) The advantage is not only that you may draw once the structure and adapt them quickly for a publication in a journal or a poster or slide talk.  As outlined in [chemscheme](http://ctan.org/pkg/chemscheme), you may add indicators as "hidden tags" in graphic that eventually allow you to comfortably label by number your compounds.  This is very beneficial in lengthier reports where you simply call these labels (similar as you would do while citing a literature reference); eventually your compound marked by **2** in the scheme is referenced by the same **2** in the running text.

Comment: I think that Chemfig is a very bad solution. As seen in the chemscheme manual that seems to be your reference, chemfig is not even mentioned. Finally, the only advantage of chemfig is its price, but that does not matters in comparison to the ease of use of commercial and paying software.

Comment: @unbonpetit What?!

Comment: @unbonpetit What, unbonpetit?! I thought you are (one of) the creator of chemfig...